# My dropdown list in codeigniter does not display a value returned from db onSelect without refreshing the page

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, codeigniter

I am trying out some code I found on the Internet which uses a dropdown list to show values from the database. Selecting an option triggers an AJAX request and the server-side controller returns some other value from the DB associated to the submitted value which then has to be displayed in a given div element on the page.

**The issue**: The controller and model logic are working fine but the value is not displayed on the page as it should be.

» **view and Javascript code**

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta content="text/html;charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
    <meta content="utf-8" http-equiv="encoding">
</head>
<body>
    <form action="" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">

    <table align="center">

        <tr>
            <td>Options :</td>
            <td>

                <?php 
                $id = 'myform';
                echo form_open($id);
                echo form_dropdown('option', $my_message); 
                echo form_close();
                ?>
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td><div id="result"></div> </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>
                <input id='submit' type="submit" value="Submit" />
            </td>
        </tr>

    </table>

</form>


    <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url();?>js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#myform").change(function(){
        $.ajax({
        type       : "POST",
        data       : $("#myform").val(),
        url        : "<?=base_url()?>index.php/fb/subCat",
        success    : function(data){
                        $("#result").val(data);
                    }
        });
    });
});
</script>
</body>
```

» **and here is my controller function:**

```
public function index() {
 $this->load->model('fb_model');
 $data['my_message'] = $this->fb_model->message();
 $this->load->view('fb_view', $data);
}

public function subCat() {
  $this->load->model('fb_model');
  $data = $this->input->post('option');
  $result = $this->fb_model->display($data);
  echo $result;
}
```

» **finally, the model to query db:**

```
public function display($data) {
  $this->db->select('id');
  $this->db->where('message', $data);
  $query = $this->db->get('content');
  foreach($query->result() as $row) {
      $records = $row->id;
  }
  return $records;
}

public function message() {
  $this->db->select('id, message');
  $this->db->order_by('message');
  $records = $this->db->get('content');
  $data=array();
  if($records->num_rows() > 0) {
    foreach($records->result_array() as $row) {
        $data[$row['id']] = $row['message'];
    }
  }
  return $data;
}
```

Thanks so much for any help

Comment: have you checked the console , for any errors ?

Comment: just print_r($data['my_message']);  and update result here.

Comment: what is ur expected output and what you are getting?

Comment: @kumar_v, I expect the value selected to be displayed after the db being updated. I am not receiving anything.

Comment: `#result` is a div, so I think in your JS you should use `html`instead of `val`: `$("#result").html(data);`. Also, your `subCat()`method should return instead of echoing.